# vscode + PHP intelephense named arguments from PHP 8.1 shown as errors

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, intelephense, php-8.1

In code written in PHP8.1 I use [named arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments) in a method call:

```
// function definition
public function myFunction(string $name, string $description = "")
// method call with errors
->myFunction(name: self::SOME_CONSTANT)
```

however extension PHP Intelephense shows 2 errors there:

`Undefined constant 'App\Some\Namespace\name'.intelephense(1011)`

 and `Unexpected ':'.intelephense(1001)`

I tried already following (with no success):

- System-wide install PHP8.1 and set it as the default version (cli version PHP 8.1.2)
- Setting these for both User && Workspace
- - `"intelephense.environment.phpVersion": "8.1.2",`
- - `"php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php8.1",`
- Restart (closing vscode completely and reopening the workspace folder again)

## EDIT / ANSWER - Update your VSCODE to LATEST!

If you're not sure where to find out - check out Help > About and then [vscode updates website](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates).
The issue in the end really was an issue of an **outdated Visual Studio Code which caused extensions not to be properly updated.** How did this happen? I was accidentally using vscode from `apt install code` which didn't update itself and it CAN be installed alongside the snap version - for ubuntu, the solution was to remove the the apt code and just keep the snap version or install it with `sudo snap install --classic code` - thanks goes to https://askubuntu.com/a/1217734/277898 for me to realize x)

Comment: What about just `php.executablePath`?

Comment: @yainspan "Unknown Configuration Setting" - I tried it anyways, no effect

Comment: What version of vscode are you using? I put in `php.executablePath` and it works fine

Comment: In fact I put in just the config you have and it works. Can you post the full code where the error is happening?

Comment: If you see intelephense 1.8 but when you install it it's older (e.g. 1.5.4) - **UPDATE YOUR VSCODE** x) thanks @yainspan